# Power series, interval of convergence

Tags: power-series

Let a power series be $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$ and if $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=0$$, then is it true that the power series converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

If that limit has the absolute value, then using the Ratio Test, this is indeed true, but does it work without the absolute value?

Comment: anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the limit is zero without absolute value, then it is also zero with absolute value.... as the absolute value map is continuous at zero.

So you get that the radius of convergence is infinite and that your power series converges everywhere.

Comment: what if there is a $(-1)^n$ in front of the series?

Comment: The absolute value of $(-1)^n$ is $1$ so there is no issue. Zero multiplied by one or minus one is still zero.

Comment: The thing that worries me is that, I know absolute convergence is stronger than convergence, so if that limit converges absolutely, then it converges, but does that works backwards?

Comment: so the answer is true?

Comment: @Logan not always. Consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$

Comment: em... so my statement is not true?

Comment: @Logan which statement? The claim in your post, or the claim that ordinary convergence implies absolute convergence?

Comment: For sure it is true! Your power series converges everywhere as $\lim \vert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \vert = 0$.

Comment: oh!!! right! that makes sense, my oogonial statement is true, my comment statement is not.

Comment: Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0):

In general absolute convergence is stronger than convergence. So knowing that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|x^n$ converges for all n, then this tells us that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ must also converge. for example by the squeeze theorem.